# Terraform conditional source in MODULE

Tags: terraform

I am trying to set a module's source (this IS NOT a resource) based on a conditional trigger but it looks like the module is getting fired before the logic is applied:

```
module "my_module" {
    source   = "${var.my_field == "" ? var.standard_repo : var.custom_repo}"
    stuff...
    more stuff...
}
```

I have created the `standard_repo` and `custom_repo` vars as well and defined with URLs for respective repos (using `git::` -- this all works w/o conditional)

All this being said, anyone know of a way to implement this conditional aspect?  (again, this is a **module** and not a **resource**)

I tried using duplicate modules and calling based off the var value but this, too, does not work (condition is never met, even when it is):

```
repo = ["${var.my_field == "na" ? module.my_module_old : module.my_module_new}"]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is described in [this post](https://medium.com/@pascal.brokmeier/how-to-conditionally-disable-modules-in-terraform-f38fdbe34f1b)

Basically, a common pattern is to have several folders for different environments such as dev/tst/prd. These environments often reuse large parts of the codebase. Some may be abstracted as modules, but there is still often a large common file which is either copy-pasted or symlinked.

The post offers a way that doesn't conditionally disable based on variables but it probably solves your issue of enabling a module based on different enviornments. It makes use of the [override feature](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html) of terraform and adds a `infra_override.tf` file. Here, it defines a different `source` for the module which points to an empty directory. Voila, a disabled module.

Comment: is using the override feature the best way to achieve this as mentioned in the article. Is this still the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not allowed to be used in the module source parameter. There also does not seem to be a plan for this to change. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1439 . Creating a wrapper script , or using something like mustache http://mustache.github.io/ seems to be the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Try to use links as hyperlinks in the post.